# How to round up a number

Tags: c#

I have variable like float num = (x/y);
I need to round up the result whenever num gives result like 34.443.
So how to do this in c#?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx):

> Returns the smallest integer greater
>   than or equal to the specified number

Note that this works on doubles, so if you want a float (or an integer) you will need to cast.

```
float num = (float)Math.Ceiling(x/y);
```

Comment: If both `x` and `y` are integers, they will be truncated.

Comment: @Josh: True.  I assumed the OP already had floats since the result was 34.443, but it's definitely worth calling that out explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

```
 float num = (x/y);
 float roundedValue = (float)Math.Round(num, 2);
```

If we use Math.Round function we can specify no of places to round.

Comment: `Math.Ceiling` - "I need to round **up**..."

Answer (score 2):

Use `Math.Ceiling` if you want the integer greater than the answer, or `Math.Floor` if you want an integer less than the answer.

Example

```
Math.Ceiling(3.46) = 4;
Math.Floor(3.46) = 3;
```

Use whichever is required for your case.

Answer (score 1):

if you need 2 decimal, yo can use something like:

```
float roundedvalue = (float)Math.Ceiling(x*100/y) /100;
float roundedvalue = (float)Math.Floor(x*100/y) /100;
```